# find substring with special chars in Elastic Search

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search. I want to search by substring, that consists of numbers and symbols like "/" and "-". For example, I create an index with default settings and one indexed field:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/" -d ' {
    "mappings" : {
            "properties": {
                    "test_field": {
                            "type": "string"
                    }
            }
    }
} '
```

Then, I add some data into my index:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/test_field" -d '{ "test_field" : "14/21-35" }'
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/test_field" -d '{ "test_field" : "1/1-35" }'
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/test_field" -d '{ "test_field" : "1/2-25" }'
```

After refreshing an index I perform searching. So, i want to find data, in which "test_field" begins with "1/1". My request:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty=true" -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"1/1*"}}}'
```

returns no hits. If i remove the **star** symbol, then in response i see two hits: "1/1-35" and "1/2-25". If i try to escape **slash** symbol by **backslash** ("1\/1*"), results are the same respectively.

When there is "-" symbol in my query, then i must escape this Lucene special character. So i send next search request:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty=true" -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*1\-3*"}}}'
```

and it returns with parsing error. If i double escape ("\\") minus, then i have no results.

I have no idea, how searching performs, when query consists of these characters. Maybe i'm doing something wrong.

I tryed to use **nGram** filter in my custom analyzer, but it doesn't suite to requirements of search engine.

If anyone encountered with this problem, please, answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default [analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/) will remove all special characters from your data at indexing time. You could use the [keyword analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-analyzer.html) or simply not analyze your data at indexing time:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/" -d ' {
    "mappings" : {
            "properties": {
                    "test_field": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
            }
    }
} '
```

Comment: I've tryed your mapping, and almost everything worked well. But not all. I have to values in my "test_field": "16/31-216" and "15/31-2". Both returns, when I search for "31". But only "15/31-2" returns, when i search for "31-2". =(

Comment: Try the [Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html) to see how your data is tokenized/filtered. If you want to do partial match, [this thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/help-needed-with-the-query-tt3177477.html#a3178856) is good explanation of the possibilities (including prefixQuery VS Edge nGrams).

Comment: After receiving a little bit of understanding, how ES works, i found solution: i needed `keyword` tokenizer with `lowercase` and `NGram` filters for `index_analyzer` and `keyword` tokenizer for `search_analyzer`. Thnx for your help!